# Accessing data outside of Vue component with Typescript

Tags: typescript, vue.js

in Vue 3, how does one use Typescript in order to preserve types on the `data` and `method` properties of a component, so those properties can be accessed from the outside? Is `Vue.defineComponent` not sufficient? See the following example:

```js
const Example = Vue.defineComponent({
  template: '<div>Incoming messages: {{ message }}</div>',
  data() {
    return {
      message: 'Here is the message'
    }
  }
})
// const Example: Vue.DefineComponent<{}, {}, {message: string;}, {}, {}, Vue.ComponentOptionsMixin, Vue.ComponentOptionsMixin, Vue.EmitsOptions, string, PublicProps, Readonly<{} & {}>, {}>

const app = Vue.createApp(Example)
// const app: Vue.App<Element>

const vm = app.mount(document.body)
// const vm: Vue.ComponentPublicInstance<{}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, false, Vue.ComponentOptionsBase<any, any, any, any, any, any, any, any, any, {}>>

console.log(vm.message) // Property 'message' does not exist on type 'ComponentPublicInstance<{}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, false, ComponentOptionsBase<any, any, any, any, any, any, any, any, any, {}>>'.
console.log(vm.$data.message); // Property 'message' does not exist on type '{}'
```

`vm.message` exists on the instantiated component, but Typescript is unaware of its existence. How can you fix this?